# Atomically reorder items in nested array of MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb

I have a document with nested array of ordered items and I need to atomically reorder items in that array.

1. are the server-side code is a right solution for this task?
2. are the server-side code is an only solution for this task?
3. at witch scope this code will blocking:

   - single document
   - single collection
   - whole server ?

this is the code that will be executed at server-side:

```
var reorder = function (
    catalog_id,
    parent_id,
    item_id,
    new_pos) {

    var old_pos;

    var collection = db.catalogs;
    var catalog = collection.findOne({catalog_id:catalog_id});
    var result = [];

    for(i in catalog.list) {

        var item = catalog.list[i];

        if(item.id == item_id) {

            old_pos = item.order;
            result.push({old_pos:old_pos});
            break;
        }
    }

    if(old_pos == new_pos)
        return result;

    var up = new_pos < old_pos;

    catalog.list.forEach(function(item){

        if( item.parent == parent_id &&
            (up ?
                (item.order <= old_pos && item.order >= new_pos) :
                (item.order <= old_pos && item.order >= new_pos))){

            if(item.id != item_id) {

                item.order++;
                result.push({down:item});
            }
            else {

                item.order = new_pos;
                result.push({up:item});
            }

            collection.update(
                {catalog_id:catalog_id, 'list.id':item.id},
                {$set:{'list.$.order':item.order}});
        }
    });

    return result;
};

reorder('diagnostic_graph', 'n1', 'n5', 1);
```

this is a sample data:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4efc939094f4a115d80c8543"),
  "catalog_id" : "diagnostic_graph",
  "list" : [{
      "id" : "n1",
      "order" : 0
    }, {
      "id" : "n2",
      "parent" : "n1",
      "order" : 0
    }, {
      "id" : "n3",
      "parent" : "n1",
      "order" : 1
    }, {
      "id" : "n4",
      "parent" : "n1",
      "order" : 2
    }, {
      "id" : "n5",
      "parent" : "n1",
      "order" : 3
    }]
}
```

PS. sorry if something is unclear - english is not my best skill

Comment: I am not sure if this operation will run atomically. To my knowledge, it can yield lock.

Comment: You could, however, calculate all this on a client and then atomically rewrite document.

Comment: I guess MongoDB guys suggest using [Update if Current](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations#AtomicOperations-%22UpdateifCurrent%22) approach (similar  to CAS ("change-and-set") in memcached) for such atomic document changes which cannot be expressed in terms of "update modifiers".

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov: Hmm, didn't see it in the docs before. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Q 1. are the server-side code is a right solution for this task?

A 1. It depends. If the array needs to be reordered whenever you use it, than you should reorder it whenever you add an item to the array. You can call server side .js code whenever you push an item to array, or do it in your application.

Q 2. are the server-side code is an only solution for this task?

A 2. As I stated in the answer of the first question, it is not the only solution.

Q 3. at witch scope this code will blocking:

A 3. The answer is single document (AFAIK).